# Why is batch normalization preserving the capacity of a network?

Tags: batch-normalization

I have a question regarding the [Batch normalization paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) of Sergey Ioffe

In the paper the author states on page 3 after discussion of derivation:

> ..., BN transform is a differentiable transformation that
>   introduces normalized activations into the network. This
>   ensures that as the model is training, layers can continue
>   learning on input distributions that exhibit less internal covariate shift, thus accelerating the training. Furthermore,
>   the learned affine transform applied to these normalized
>   activations allows the BN transform to represent the identity transformation and preserves the network capacity

**Question**
Why is this at all related to preserving the network capacity?

**Edit:**
I read up a little now and think as the normalization is just like a copy process that does not change the number of parameters the author just makes this statement to ensure the benefit of this method. I first thought there is some twist here that makes the notion of capacity important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a sense for why batch normalization is important, consider a neural network with two hidden layers, $h^1$ and $h^2$, and inputs $x$, so that the input to $h^2$ depends on the activation of $h^1$.  However, during SGD, the parameters of both hidden layers are changing , so that the distribution of the activations of $h^1$ are constantly changing (different mean, different standard deviation, etc).  This makes it difficult to accurately optimize the weights of $h^2$, since the weights are having to continuously react and update to the new distribution of inputs from the activations of $h^1$.

In this way, batch normalization aims to reduce this so-called "covariance shift" in the inputs to $h^2$, so that training can proceed smoother. They do this by standardizing each layer's activations.  Let $a^1$ denote the activations of the first hidden layer.  The standardized versions, $\hat{a}^1$ are given by:

$$\hat{a}^1 = \frac{a^1 - \overline{a}^1}{\text{SD}(a^1)}$$

Where $\overline{a}$ denotes the empirical mean, and SD denotes the standard deviation.  In this way, we ensure that the inputs to $h^2$ will always have mean 0 and standard deviation 1.

However, this process of standardization throws away a lot of information about the previous layer, which may lead to a decreased ability for the model to learn complicated interactions - this is the notion of **capacity** you were referring to.  BatchNorm resolves this by adding two parameters, $\gamma$ and $\beta$, again trained by backpropogation, that allows us to "add back" some information of the previous layer:

$$y^1 = \gamma\hat{a}^1 + \beta$$

The $y^1$'s are now used as input for $h^2$.  Note that when $\gamma = \text{SD}(a)$, and $\beta = \overline{a}$, we recover the original inputs, which is the identity transform the original paper was referring to.  And, when $\gamma = 1, \; \beta = 0$, we again have our completely standardized inputs.  In this way, we allow for a balance between reducing the effects of covariance shift, while simultaneously maintaining the expressiveness of our neural network.